# Android does not make the BLE findme device beep

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to implement the application which will communicate with BLE findme device. I have the one of these devices, but have some problem with it. Using iPhone I have tested this device with bleTools application and this app works correctly, i.e. I have managed to read all device's characterictics and send the characteristics to make the device beep. But using Android (Nexus 5) I could only read the device's characteristics, but cannot make the device beep. 
My code is:

```
 private static final UUID IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE =
        UUID.fromString("00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private static final UUID IMMEDIATE_ALERT_LEVEL =
        UUID.fromString("00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

...

```
public void beep(DeviceData device) {
        BluetoothGatt gatt = mConnectedDevices.get(device.getDeviceAddress());
        BluetoothGattService bluetoothGattService = gatt.getService(IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE);
        if (bluetoothGattService == null) {
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                bluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(IMMEDIATE_ALERT_LEVEL);
        if (characteristic == null) {
            return;
        }        

        byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1];
        arrayOfByte[0] = (byte) 0x01;
        characteristic.setValue(arrayOfByte);
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}
```

The callback method returns Ok:

```
@Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            if (characteristic.getUuid().toString().equals(IMMEDIATE_ALERT_LEVEL.toString())) {
                //TODO: use device address to identify the device-receiver
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = MSG_PARAM_WRITTEN;
                msg.obj = (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS);

                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }
```

but nothing happens on the device side.

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong or maybe give some advice what should I do?

And again, I can read the device characteristics, but cannot write them to the device.

Comment: well I'm trying the same thing, from where did get the UUIDs?? cause when I try to list all the services UUIDs of the device, I didn't get the one you have!

Comment: To narrow down where is the problem use this app https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Nordic-mobile-Apps/nRF-Master-Control-Panel-application - I'm able to start alert with this app on my "findme" device.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike iOS, Android has quite a few undocumented tricks with Bluetooth.  I'm assuming you are using the standard Bluetooth library included in Android 4.3 and later.  If you using other libraries like Samsung or Broadcom, the results could be different.

Because I do not have a findeme device I cannot confirm anything. But I have worked with both classic and low energy Bluetooth energy on Android for a while now.  My advice is to go through the complete process of scan, discover services and read/write characteristics.

1. startLeScan
2. onLeScanCallBack connect to the device
3. onConnect discoverServices
4. onServicesDiscovered get all characteristics
5. check the properties on each characteristic
6. if you can read it, go ahead and do that
7. after that is done, you can then write the characteristic and listen for the onCharacteristicWrite event. You may get the beep then.  If not, you'll need to go back to the iOS project and trace every bit that is sent to and received from the findme device.  That sounds difficult but it's really just a matter of reading bytes inside of the right delegates.  Document that. Then go back and recreate the bit sequence on the Android side. Again, capture all the traffic to and from the findme device.  If you can get the bit sequence to match, you'll have success.

There's one more very important thing to know about Android BLE.  The writes must be sequential.  By that I mean, if you write a characteristic, you must wait for the onCharacteristic event to fire before you can write another one.  This is not documented on the Android developer site.  The best way to implement this functionality is to use a LinkedList as a work queue.

Good luck and ping me if you have questions.